# join two tables but get the last record in each group in the second table mysql

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I'm having two tables: users and visits. In visits every user has multiple visits. What I want to do it to join these two tables to get the user data like id, user_name, User_email and the last visit record like url,unix_time. I used this code but now it's taking too long to finish to get just users who has no visits in the last two weeks

Table users:

```
user_id    user_name        user_email
   1          foo          foo@mail.com
   2          bar          bar@mail.com
```

Table visits

```
   id       user_id        unix_time              page
    1         1           (unixtime value)     visited page url
    2         2           (unixtime value)     visited page url
    3         1           (unixtime value)     visited page url
    4         2           (unixtime value)     visited page url
```

The expected result is: (every user with his last visit from the visits table)

```
 id    user_id    user_name   user_email      unix_time         page
  3       1          foo      foo@mail.com    (unixtime value)  visited page url
  4       2          bar      bar@mail.com    (unixtime value)  visited page url
```

Query:

```
$two_weeks_before = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-2 weeks"));
$month_before = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 month"));

SELECT m1.* FROM visits_log m1 
LEFT JOIN visits_log m2 ON (m1.user_id = m2.user_id AND m1.id < m2.id)
WHERE m2.id IS NULL and m1.admin != '1' and
from_unixtime(m1.unix_time) < '$two_weeks_before' and
from_unixtime(m1.unix_time) > '$month_before'
```

So I'm looking for a query that gets the same result but executes faster.

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking for. in title you want to get latest visits, but in your post you are asking for _users who has no visits_  Please clarify. try to provide data sample and expected result. sqlfiddle would be very helpful

Comment: Same comment, i don't understand what you want. In the query you use a LEFT JOIN and in your explanation you told us it was an INNER JOIN. Can you put the expected result ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Your question is still not 100% clear and your data sample is not complete.

But here my attempt where you can start from:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a9b7/1

```
SELECT u.*, v.* FROM users u
LEFT JOIN visits v
ON u.user_id = v.user_id
  AND v.unix_time > now()- INTERVAL 2 WEEK
```